# Pair-matched count regression in R with offset?

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, count-data, offset

I need to conduct a pair-matched count regression in R.

Specifically, my data looks as follows:

| ID | Exposure | Occurrence | Area |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 7 | 50 |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 55 |
| 2 | 0 | 6 | 70 |
| 2 | 1 | 8 | 74 |
| 3 | 0 | 4 | 45 |
| 3 | 1 | 9 | 62 |

I need the outcome to be based on a relative rate per square feet (area), so I want to use an offset.

While I would think this wouldn't be too difficult, I am hitting a wall on my Google search as pair-matched data is so frequently done with a binary outcome.

Do you know a good package or a way to be able to do this?

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to do this with a mixed model with a count response (e.g. Poisson or negative binomial): you want the "standard" count-GLM-with-offset model with random variation in the intercept across IDs:

$$
\begin{split}
\eta_{ij} &  = \beta_0 + b_i + \beta_1 E_{ij} + \log(A_{ij}) \\
b_i & \sim N(0, \sigma^2_b) \\
O_{ij} & \sim \textrm{Poisson}(\exp(\eta_{ij}))
\end{split}
$$
where $i$ indexes IDs and $j = \{1,2\}$ indexes observations within IDs.  $\beta_0$ denotes the overall (population-level) intercept; $b_i$ denotes the random effects, i.e. the deviation of the intercept from the population-level value for each group. (Most mixed-model software will let you estimate the *conditional modes* of the $b_i$ distributions, equivalent to BLUPs (best linear unbiased predictors) in the linear mixed model case.) $A_{ij}$ is the area for the $i,j$th observation (i.e. observation $j$ within group $i$), $O_{ij}$ is the occurrence (count response).

If you specified that the model be fitted by *restricted maximum likelihood* (which is possible for GLMMs in `glmmTMB` and possibly some other packages), this specification is exactly analogous to a paired t-test, but with Poisson rather than Gaussian responses. If you use maximum likelihood or Bayesian methods (which are more common), it's still pretty close to a "paired Poisson t-test" equivalent.

Since you asked how to do this in R: in `lme4` (for example) it would be

```r
glmer(observation ~ exposure + offset(log(area)) + (1|ID),
      family = poisson,
      data = ...)
```

Similar models can be fitted lots of different packages/functions, some with very similar interfaces (`lme4::glmer`, `glmmTMB::glmmTMB`), some with different interfaces (`GLMMadaptive`), some Bayesian (`MCMCglmm`, `rstanarm`, `brms`), etc.

Comment: Hi, can you clarify what some of the variables above are standing in for? For example, bi compared to B0?

Comment: @revere2323 $\beta_0$ is the overall model intercept (i.e., the fixed intercept), and $b_i$ is the randomly varying effect for each unit $i$. $b_i$ is specified to have a Normal distribution, and the fact that it varies across individuals and has a probability distribution associated with it is what makes this a mixed model. I infer that $O_{ij}$ is the occurrence for observation $j$ of unit $i$, and $E_{ij}$ is the exposure. $\beta_1$ is the coefficient on exposure, i.e., the ID-conditional exposure effect. This is all described in the paragraph under the regression equation.

Comment: Thanks, Noah.  Some of what's in your comment was edited in shortly before you commented .